# Get the sum of the Count of several Lists in a C# Class

Tags: c#, list, class, count

I have a Class whose properties are as follows

```
    {
        public ICollection<MyType> List1 { get; set; } =
            new List<MyType>();

        public ICollection<MyType> List2 { get; set; } =
            new List<MyType>();

        public ICollection<MyType> List3 { get; set; } =
            new List<MyType>();
    }
```

I would like to get the sum of `List1.Count + List2.Count + List3.Count` (and so on if I had more lists). How do you I go about it in C#? In JS, I would use something like a for...in loop and check for the type of the property. Is there any way to do that in C#?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection.count?view=net-6.0 what is wrong with `List1.Count + List2.Count` etc.?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking about, is it reflection?

Comment: @Trevor for different classes, I would have different amount of lists, with different names. it eventually feels a little dumb to just copy and paste.

Comment: @Blindy I think reflection is probably one way to solve it, but I'm basically asking how to loop through the properties of a class, and get the properties of these properties.

Comment: That is reflection. And you're right, your pattern is very dumb. Use proper structured objects instead, not whatever those separate lists of objects that somehow get added together in count are.

Comment: @Blindy I don't understand what you mean by "proper structured objects", or how they would help here.

Comment: It's easy, ask yourself why three separate collection properties should be counted together and why they aren't just one collection property of a proper type. Whatever the answer to that question is, is the answer to your question as well.

Comment: @Blindy Thanks, I think I get it. Those lists are separated because each is a category of MyType, maybe simply adding a Category property in MyType will solve the issue rather neatly.

Comment: Or an inheritance structure, depending on what those objects are. Either way, my point is that you are treating them all as if they were the same kinds of objects (at least insofar as counting them together), but are separating them in memory, that's a code smell if I've ever seen (smelled) one.

Comment: Given a class with those properties, you'd have to either add the counts manually or use reflection to find and access the properties which are lists. But you might want to reconsider your model: maybe you should be using a `Dictionary<string, List<MyType>>()`, for example, so you can add any number of lists associated with property names, and then you can just use `.Values.Sum(v => v.Count)` to sum up the counts.

Comment: ... or, taking your idea of adding a Category property to MyType, you just use `.Sum()` on the collection of all the `MyType`s, and if you need a structure that lets you find the types in a given category you can say `myTypes.ToLookup(mt => mt.Category)`.